# Show value of nearest td on button click

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

I have a GridView that's dynamically generated from a database.
At the beginning of every row ther's a button.
When button(myBtn) is clicked it should show text value of the column from the right side(where class is ObjectID) in every row.

All the code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvmyObject" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="GridView" >

        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
               <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                <button class="myBtn" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="vertical-align:middle"><span>Select</span></button>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ObjectID" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="ObjectID" runat="server" class="ObjectID" Width="118px" Height="26px"  style="text-align:center" Font-Names="Georgia" margin-Left="100px" Text='<%# Bind("ObjectID") %>'></asp:Label>


                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ObjectName">
                <ItemTemplate>

                    <asp:Label ID="ObjectName" runat="server" Width="118px" Height="26px" style="text-align:center" Font-Names="Georgia" margin-Left="100px" Text='<%# Bind("ObjectName") %>'></asp:Label>

                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="OtherID">
                <ItemTemplate>

                    <asp:Label ID="OtherID" runat="server" Width="118px" Height="26px" style="text-align:center" Font-Names="Georgia" margin-Left="100px" Text='<%# Bind("OtherID") %>'></asp:Label>

                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SmallID">
                <ItemTemplate>

                    <asp:Label ID="SmallID" runat="server" Width="118px" Height="26px" style="text-align:center" Font-Names="Georgia" margin-Left="100px" Text='<%# Bind("SmallID") %>'></asp:Label>

                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>



    </asp:GridView>


   <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Request modification</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">

                           Modal data
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" onClick="refreshPage()" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I have some code but it does not work. I tried everything :/

```
   $(document).on('click', ".myBtn", function () {
            console.log($(this).closest('td').find('.ObjectID').text());

 });
```

This is jsfiddle code:

https://jsfiddle.net/1v0tm84f/7/

Basically it should show 316 in the first row and 240 in the second row on the button click.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should point to the element that contains the entire row  (TR), in order to retrieve data from that row just like the example.

```js
$(document).on('click', ".myBtn", function () {
            console.log($(this).closest('tr').find('.ObjectID').text());
           
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="GridView" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" id="MainContent_gvObjekat" style="color:#333333;border-collapse:collapse;">
  <tr style="color:White;background-color:#507CD1;font-weight:bold;">
   <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th><th scope="col">ObjectID</th><th scope="col">ObjectName</th><th scope="col">OtherID</th><th scope="col">SmallID</th>
  </tr><tr style="background-color:#EFF3FB;">
   <td>
                    <button class="myBtn" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="vertical-align:middle"><span>Select</span></button>
                    </td><td>
                        <span id="MainContent_gvObject_ObjectID_0" class="ObjectID" margin-Left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:26px;width:118px;text-align:center">316</span>
                         

                    </td><td>

                        <span id="MainContent_gvObject_ObjectName_0" margin-Left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:26px;width:118px;text-align:center">MYTEST1</span>

                    </td><td>

                        <span id="MainContent_gvObject_OtherID_0" margin-Left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:26px;width:118px;text-align:center">2</span>

                    </td><td>

                        <span id="MainContent_gvObject_SmallID_0" margin-Left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:26px;width:118px;text-align:center">229</span>

                    </td>
  </tr><tr style="background-color:White;">
   <td>
                    <button class="myBtn" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="vertical-align:middle"><span>Select</span></button>
                    </td><td>
                        <span id="MainContent_gvObjekat_ObjekatID_1" class="ObjectID" margin-Left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:26px;width:118px;text-align:center">240</span>
                         

                    </td><td>

                        <span id="MainContent_gvObjekat_ObjekatName_1" margin-Left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:26px;width:118px;text-align:center">MYTEST3</span>

                    </td><td>

                        <span id="MainContent_gvObjekat_BusinessCenterID_1" margin-Left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:26px;width:118px;text-align:center">1</span>

                    </td><td>

                        <span id="MainContent_gvObjekat_ParentObjekatID_1" margin-Left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:26px;width:118px;text-align:center">229</span>

                    </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try it

js

```
$(document).click(function() {
            console.log($(this).closest('tr').find('.ObjectID').text());

 });
```

Html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="GridView" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" id="MainContent_gvObjekat" style="color:#333333;border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr style="color:White;background-color:#507CD1;font-weight:bold;">
            <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th><th scope="col">ObjectID</th><th scope="col">ObjectName</th><th scope="col">OtherID</th><th scope="col">SmallID</th>
        </tr><tr style="background-color:#EFF3FB;">
            <td>
                    <button class="myBtn" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="vertical-align:middle"><span>Select</span></button>
                    </td><td>
                        <span id="MainContent_gvObject_ObjectID_0" class="ObjectID" margin-Left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:26px;width:118px;text-align:center">316</span>


                    </td><td>

                        <span id="MainContent_gvObject_ObjectName_0" margin-Left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:26px;width:118px;text-align:center">MYTEST1</span>

                    </td><td>

                        <span id="MainContent_gvObject_OtherID_0" margin-Left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:26px;width:118px;text-align:center">2</span>

                    </td><td>

                        <span id="MainContent_gvObject_SmallID_0" margin-Left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:26px;width:118px;text-align:center">229</span>

                    </td>
        </tr><tr style="background-color:White;">
            <td>
                    <button class="myBtn" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="vertical-align:middle"><span>Select</span></button>
                    </td><td>
                        <span id="MainContent_gvObjekat_ObjekatID_1" class="ObjectID" margin-Left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:26px;width:118px;text-align:center">240</span>


                    </td><td>

                        <span id="MainContent_gvObjekat_ObjekatName_1" margin-Left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:26px;width:118px;text-align:center">MYTEST3</span>

                    </td><td>

                        <span id="MainContent_gvObjekat_BusinessCenterID_1" margin-Left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:26px;width:118px;text-align:center">1</span>

                    </td><td>

                        <span id="MainContent_gvObjekat_ParentObjekatID_1" margin-Left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:26px;width:118px;text-align:center">229</span>

                    </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: $(document).click(function(e) { 
  console.log($(e.target).closest('tr').find('.ObjectID').text());});